# How to add XML Declaration to XML Files written using Spark XML Data-bricks

Tags: xml, scala, apache-spark

I wanted to create an XML file with XML declaration from the CSV/Dataframe using Scala in spark.  I am using Databricks spark-XML library for converting the DataFrame to XML format.

**Sample Code**

```
spark.sql("Select 1 as id")..write \
.format('com.databricks.spark.xml') \
.options(rowTag='row', rootTag='rows') \
.save('Sample.xml')
```

***Dataframe***

```
+---+
| id|
+---+
|  1|
+---+
```

**Actual Output**

```
<rows>
<row>
<id>1<id>
</row>
</rows>
```

**Expected Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding"UTF-8">
    <rows>
    <row>
    <id>1<id>
    </row>
    </rows>
```

can anyone help add version and encoding element in the XML generated by data-bricks XML?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: can we see the input dataframe?

Comment: @RameshMaharjan added the input data frame

Comment: the code looks like its in pyspark

Comment: @devanathan Please share the code, if you have figured it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use:

```
your_dataframe.to_xml('file_name_to_save_to.xml', xml_declaration = True)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).